# Powershell script to send contents of files in a directory to write-output

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with the following files:

```
C:\temp\installer_logs\main.log
C:\temp\installer_logs\component1.log
C:\temp\installer_logs\component2.log
```

I need a Powershell script that gets a list of all files in C:\temp\installer_logs and sends the contents of each file to Write-Output. The following does not work. Help?

```
dir -Recurse C:\temp\installer_logs | Get-ChildItem | Select FullName | Write-Output
```

Comment: you have not loaded the CONTENT of any file, only the filesystem info about the files. take a look at `Get-Help *content*` for some nifty examples of what you need to do.

Comment: What is the error that PowerShell is writing in the Shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny thing about PowerShell, but commands like `dir` and `ls` are actually just aliases for `Get-ChildItem`, so the first two commands in your chain actually do the same thing.

Let's look at what you need to do:

1. Get a list of files
2. Get the Contents of each of those files
3. Output each of the contents to Write-Output

Looking at this step by step, we need to

1. dir -Recurse C:\temp\installer_logs
2. For each of the above `Get-Content` to read the data from the file
3. Pipe that content to Write-Output

Assuming that is correct, this will do what you are looking for:

```
dir -Recurse -File C:\temp\installer_logs | % {Get-Content $_.FullName} | Write-Output
```

Added the -File option to get only files.  Can remove if necessary
% is an alias for the ForEach-Object cmdlet
$_ is the current object, and the .FullName property gives you the full path

EDIT: The ForEach-Object is only necessary for cmdlets which do not accept pipeline input themselves.  Since the Get-Content cmdlet understands Get-ChildItem objects in the pipeline, my answer can be simplified to:

```
dir -Recurse -File C:\temp\installer_logs | Get-Content | Write-Output
```

And, tbh, not sure if the Write-Output is necessary either.  Leaving it off seems to do exactly the same thing as far as I can see.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Answer to 1st comment...

I always tell my co-workers that the answer to "is this possible?" is always "yes". Sometimes too resource intensive or expensive, but nearly never not possible. Try something like this:

```
dir -Recurse -File C:\temp\installer_logs | % {"----- $($_.FullName) -----";Get-Content $_.FullName} | Write-Output
```

Not even sure the "Write-Output" is necessary unless you're trying to redirect somewhere other than the screen.

Comment: This is great! I am attempting to integrate this into a release pipeline in Azure DevOps. I would like to format the output such that it was something like the following. Is this possible?
```
---------- C:\temp\installer_logs\main.log ----------
Contents of the log file here
---------- C:\temp\installer_logs\component1.log ----------
Contents of the log file here
---------- C:\temp\installer_logs\component2.log ----------
Contents of the log file here
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! This is a godsend. I really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If this helped you achieve your goal, it would be appreciated if you accepted this answer.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a Get-Content in there to actually read the contents and pass them to Write-Output

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\installer_logs | Get-Content | Write-Output
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dir -Recurse C:\temp\installer_log *.log  | Get-ChildItem | Get-Content
```

Cheers,

~G

Comment: dir & Get-ChildItem are the same thing.  Your chain asks PS to get a recursive directory listing, and then for each item it finds, get the item again before passing it on to Get-Content.  You don't need the Get-ChildItem if you're already using dir, which is an alias for Get-ChildItem.